# What approach should i use while integrating Azure AD authentication to the pre-existing project consist of API and MVC?

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory

Right now whats going on:

I have two ASP.Net application, one is for front end and another one is an API governing the front end. Right now in my application, when the user gets to the login page the user needs to enter the credentials(username and password) the from that credentials are being send to an API to create the session for user and validate it.

What's need to be added:

Now I want to add "Sign in through Azure" button which will authenticate the user and get the required attribute  in order to validate the user.

What should be my approach in order to achieve this? Like How I can add this functionality to my API which already consist of Startup Class?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for web app that signs in users and  then calls the backend api on behalf of that user.
For that you can go through the entire process with steps shown here in ***[A web app that authenticates users and calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview).***

Firstly register an application that signs users in by signing into the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/).

[image]
Then give proper permissions (delegated) to access web api and expose api of your app.

You can see the further details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app)
Then add some code configuration like in appsettings ,in startup.cs etc to add microsoft idenitity platform to the web app as shown in [code configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration)

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "[Client_id-of-web-app]",
    "TenantId": "common",
   // To call an API
   "ClientSecret": "[Copy the client secret added to the app from the Azure portal]",
  
  ]
 },
```

Reference: [Azure-Samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API)